# Etymology of "geteilt durch"

Tags: etymology

- Why does one say for instance "*6 geteilt durch 2 ist 3*"?
- Why "*geteilt durch*" but not "*geteilt auf*"?

What you actually mean is

> "6 Dinge aufteilen auf 2 Personen, und jeder bekommt 3".

Comment: In diesem Fall kann man durch als von verstehen... damit ist der Sinn wiederhergestellt.  Es werde 6 Dinge von 2 Personen aufgeteilt und dadurch erhält jeder 3. Aber das ist jetzt (fast) nur Spekulation.

Comment: @Vogel612: Die Eltern (2 Personen) teilen die Schokokugeln (6) auf 3 Kinder auf. Es wird zwar von 2 Personen geteilt aber nicht von dreien. Es wird auch nicht auf 2 aufgeteilt sondern auf 3.

Comment: It's likely meant vice versa, and it's "6 Dinge aufteilen, von 2 durchgeführt, und jeder der 2 nimmt sich 3." where *von ... durchgeführt* is expressed with *durch*. But this is just a theory.

Comment: Adam Ries (http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Adam_Risen_Rechenbuch) verwendet `teilen durch` und `teilen mit`, ist aber auch bei anderen Rechenoperationen nicht einheitlich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Konstruktion

> durch etwas teilen

für die mathematische Operation des Dividierens ist eine wortwörtliche Übersetzung des Lateinischen

> dividere per

Comment: und *per* ist im Sinne von *mittels* gemeint?

Comment: @falkb Ich kenne mich im Latein nicht so gut aus, aber ich schätze ja.

Comment: Ich verstehe nur nicht, warum genau aus dem Lateinischen (nicht aus dem alten Ägyptischen oder aus dem Griechigschen). Geht es hier um das mathematische Erbe, um sprachliches Erbe, ... ?

Comment: @c.p. Weil `dividere per` Latein ist und nicht Altägyptisch oder Altgriechisch. Zumindest Altägyptisch konnte im relevanten Zeitraum keiner.

Comment: @Toscho Ja, ich habe die Frage falsch gestellt. Demjenige (mir), der kein Latein kann, ist doch schwierig zu verstehen, wie das Vokabel ins Deutsche kam. Ich meine, warum die Antwort nicht so lauten könnte: "Die Konstruktion *durch etwas teilen* für die mathematische Operation des Dividierens ist eine wortwörtliche Übersetzung des Altgrichischen `(was auch immer in Altgrichischen das Äquivalent ist)`" D. h. was verweist, dass das Vokabel eben aus dem Lateinischen kommt?

Comment: @c.p. Ahja. Die Tatsache, dass statt der Übersetzung `teilen` auch das Lehnwort `dividieren` verwendet wird, deutet für mich sehr stark darauf hin, dass es aus dem Latein stammt.

Comment: @Toscho Ach so, das meints du +1. Ich wusste nicht einmal, dass dividieren ein deutsches Wort war.

Answer (score 8):

The expression has its roots in the **passive** voice when the *Täter* are abstract entities (means), not persons:

> Der Apfel wird vom Kind gegessen. (der Täter ist hier *das Kind*)
>
> Sein Ziel wurde nur durch harte, tägliche Arbeit erreicht. (der Täter ist hier kein Wesen, sondern *Arbeit*, ein Mittel)

According to [*Canoonet.eu*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Genera/Vorgangspass.html#Anchor-Angabe-47857) *Arbeit* plays the role of *Vermittler*. A passive with *durch* it signals the mean an action is accomplished with. So

> *6 geteilt durch 2 ist 3*

shorthand for something like

> Wenn 6 durch 2 geteilt wird, ist das Ergebnis 3.

Here, of course, *zwei* is the means you use to divide.

Of course there's no reason to think that this expression in German should match the English one, but it does:

> *6 divided by 2 is 3*

is also a passive voice.

Comment: Du erklärst sehr gut, was hinter dem genannten Fakt von Toscho steht. Das lateinische 'dividere per' hat sicherlich genau diesen Hintergrund, den du beschreibst. Schade, dass man Bounties nicht durch 2 teilen kann.

Answer (score 4):

Das im mathematischen Sinn richtige Wort wäre nicht `teilen`, sondern `dividieren`, analog zu `addieren,` `subtrahieren` und `multiplizieren`. Jedes dieser Worte hat seine eigene, eindeutige Präposition - `addieren zu`, `subtrahieren von`, `multiplizieren mit`, `dividieren durch`.

Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch werden die mathematischen Verben jedoch nicht verwendet, sondern durch ersetzt durch `zusammenzählen`, `abziehen von`, `malnehmen mit` und `teilen durch`. In allen diese Fällen werden die Präpositionen übernommen - `teilen` erbt in diesem Fall das `durch` von `dividieren`. In nicht-mathematischen Zusammenhängen behält das Wort seine eigentliche Präposition.

Comment: Any idea why `dividieren` comes with `durch`? Doesn't `dividieren` has in Latin actually the same meaning as `teilen`?

Comment: Yes, the latin verb means the same, and it uses `in` as well (`Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres...` from Caesar's `de Bello Gallico`). I couldn't find any historical german texts, so i can only guess it comes from explanations like `Durch die 5 wird die 15 in 3 Teile dividiert`, analoguous to english `By the 5, the 15 gets divided in 3 parts`. The `durch` resp. `by` is what stuck, not the `in`.

Comment: multiplizieren mit, malnehmen mit... In der selben Kategorie kommt auch "vervielfachen", oder?

Comment: @SylvainGadenne Ich würde "vervielfachen" nicht im mathematischen Kontext oder mit einer konkreten Zahl verwenden. "Ich vervielfache den Brief mit einem Kopierer" ist ok, aber "ich vervielfache den Brief mit 3" geht überhaupt nicht, das müsste dann "ich vervielfache den Brief 3 Mal" sein.

Comment: Vielen Dank @Guntram Blohm!

Answer (score 3):

Concerning **the second question**:

> Why "geteilt durch" but not "geteilt auf"?

It is

> aufteilen auf
>   teilen durch

For instance

> Wenn man 6 Liter Wasser **auf** 2 Personen **aufteilt**, bekommt jeder 3 Liter.
>   Wenn man 6 Liter Wasser **durch** 2 Personen **teilt**, bekommt jeder 3 Liter.

Now it is possible to say (even though it is not used in context of maths)

> 6 **aufgeteilt** auf 2 ist 3.

But in an equation it is *always*

> 6 geteilt durch 2 ist 3

But I have not the slightest idea, why it is *geteilt durch*. Indeed *geteilt durch* is connected to the notion of *passen in*, but still *aufgeteilt auf* seems to me even more vivid.

Answer (score 3):

Teilen literally means sharing in German. The same concept you have in English when you are talking about shares in a company. Each share is equal and is a share of a bigger whole. The whole is shared by or divided amongst or divided through or by or owned by or split up in shares.

The important point is that division or teilung results in equally large parts. Only then you can say the big thing is being shared (equally) by or geteilt durch x number of people or support beams or ships or cargo containers or monetary units.

And an equal division does not preclude the subsequent subdivision or sub multiplication of formerly equal shares into other groupings.

Answer (score 2):

As is most often the case, it is simply a matter of just being an established convention.
IDIOM if you like. And idiom is by definition non-explicit. Also prepositions e.g. *durch*
or *through* are inconsistently used in different languages "den ganzen Tag über",
(*through the day*).

Now while *durch* seems to suggest a flow of stuff between recipients, *geteilt auf* might have, by an accident of history, become the most fitting idiom for the act of arithmetical division.

Answer (score 0):

In English, we say 6 divided by 2 is 3.

The German equivalent is more like  "6 divided **through** by 2 is 3" (durch=through). The other preposition, "auf," is not used in this context. To take Em1's point, "It is what it is."

Comment: Wenn, dann `6 divided through 2 is 3`, oder? Nicht `through by`

Comment: Well, if your point is that "it is as it is" then you should say it. But otherwise the question is about *why* is it like that. What would your answer be why you say "divided by" and not "divided through"?

Comment: @Em1: So noted and added. I think the English expression you want is "It is what it is."